# How can I get training accuracy output in Keras?

Tags: keras

I use `fit_generator(data_generator, steps_per_epoch=total/batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=2,callbacks=mylist)` in Keras during training, while I don't know how to let it print training accuracy while training?
It seems like it's doing the training without any info printed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) for `fit` (same case for `fit_generator`):

> **verbose**: 0 for no logging to stdout, 1 for progress bar logging, 2 for one log line per epoch.

Here is the output for the [MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py):

- with `verbose=2` (your case):

  ```
  Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
  Epoch 1/2
   - 298s - loss: 0.3323 - acc: 0.8983 - val_loss: 0.0735 - val_acc: 0.9763
  Epoch 2/2
   - 305s - loss: 0.1111 - acc: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0502 - val_acc: 0.9838
  ```

where training `loss` and `acc` are indeed available, but only *after the end* of each epoch.

- with `verbose=1` (snapshot):

  ```
  Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
  Epoch 1/2
  25088/60000 [===========>..................] - ETA: 2:51 - loss: 0.5471 - acc: 0.8305
  ```

where training `loss` and `acc` are available *during* the epoch, along with a progress bar.

Since it seems you are looking for the second case, change to `verbose=1`.